# Use a frame less splash screen (no tittlebar and menubar ) in AngularJS node-webkit application

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

Is there any way to show a frame less splash screen in node-webkit application? 
My current package.json looks like below

```
{
"name": "myapp",
"main": "index.html",
"window": {
    "toolbar": false,
    "width": 590,
    "height": 490,
    "icon": "./images/app_icon.png",
    "title": "My App Tittle"
  },
"version":"2014"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `"frame": false` inside your window object (in your `package.json` file), it will make your main window frameless. From there you just need to create a pause, before spawning a new window with your main app loaded in it.